# Corrs issue in Angular HTTP get

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, get, cross-domain

I am trying call an api as below:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', `bearer `+this.getTokenFromStorage());
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get(Appconfig.HISURL + 'api/User/GetUserDetails/' + soeid, options);
```

Error shown below

> err = HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401,
>   statusText: "Unauthorized", url:
>   "http://localhost:54721/api/User/GetUserDetails/MA12345", ok: false,
>   …}

But i take the values and pass it on POSTMAN, it hit the API without any issues, what i am missing?

Comment: why don't you use interceptors for adding the headers? If you are using httpClient.

Comment: what change i need to do for using interceptors

Comment: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8 check this one.

Comment: is there any alternative without this?

Comment: thanks for the tips ..i got solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the new `HttpClient` (deduced from the fact that you get a `HttpErrorResponse`), but you pass in the wrong header instance: you are using `Headers` (angular 2-4) instead of `HttpHeaders` (angular 4-6)

Try that

```
import {HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common.http;

//...

let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `bearer `+this.getTokenFromStorage());

return this.http.get(Appconfig.HISURL + 'api/User/GetUserDetails/' + soeid, {headers});
```

Also passing the `Access-Control-...` headers client side is useless, since they are meant to be set server side

Comment: Thanks  a ton! Its worked like a charm! You are STAR!!

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to look at [proxy conf](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) ?

Create a file `proxy.conf.json` with something like that :

```
 {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:54721",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
```

Then you just have to do your API call without any CORS headers.

Don't forget to add `--proxy-config proxy.conf.json` to your start script.

Comment: where should i add this? in the above script?

Comment: In a file call `proxy.conf.json`

Comment: hope fully this is a work around not a solution, since we use proxy..am i right?

Comment: This is working only in a development environment. In a production environment the back-end should be on the same url and port than your Angular app. 

If you want to make some API call to an external API you should add CORS authorization in this API, not in your Angular app. But allow cross-domain requests isn't recommended for security reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
let url = 'API_URL';
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.getHeadersWithAuthToken() });
return this.http.get(url,options).map(response => response.json());

getHeadersWithAuthToken(): Headers {
    return new Headers(
      {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Authorization': `bearer `+localStorage.getItem("token")
      });
  }
```

Comment: If you are using "HttpClient" for accesing the http methods then it will give same error. Try to use "private http: Http" and access http methods with this.